# Ball slides down

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I've kept a ball between one fixed and another mobile surface of same height (say two books one which functions as a fixed support while other is moved on about by me). While I pull one of the books, the ball starts coming down which implies that $mg$ overpowers normal by the surfaces.

Well then at some instant, I stop pulling the book, then the ball also comes to rest. Why is it so? Why can't the normal always be enough to keep it rest with respect to the y axis?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the normal due to the contact surface prevents the ball from falling, but it is the one which provides necessary friction to balance out the weight of the given ball.

When you remove the contact surface(book in this case), then the necessary friction required to prevent the ball from falling vanishes and ball falls due to net downward force.